# Check for status of subprocess to kill audio playback in python

Tags: python, subprocess, kill, sox

Im currently using sox to apply effects to an audio file and play the file back. Currently I have the code set to create a new subprocess to play the file when button 1 is pressed and to kill the process when button 2 is pressed.

What I want to do is change it so that if Button 1 is pressed multiple times it will check to see if a previous process is active and if so kill it and if not then just play as normal.

My code as of now is:

```
def Button_1():
    p = subprocess.Popen(['play','playback.wav'])

def Button_2():
    p.send_signal(signal.SIGNIT)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`p.poll()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.poll) to check if the process is still running.

The code will look something like this (untested):

```
def Button_1():
    if p.poll():
        p.send_signal(signal.SIGNIT)
    else:
        p = subprocess.Popen(['play','playback.wav'])

def Button_2():
    p.send_signal(signal.SIGNIT)
```